# Why aren't both variables undefined?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Why don't the lines `console.log(VipUser);` and `console.log(DummyUser);` both throw an error? Why don't both display "undefined" if you run this code in a
browser?

```js
(function() {
  var User = function(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
  };
  User.prototype.welcome = function() {
    console.log('Welcome ' + this.name);
  };
  User.prototype.getAge = function() {
    return this.age;
  };
  console.log(VipUser);
  console.log(DummyUser);

  function DummyUser(name, surname) {
    this.name = name;
    this.surname = surname;
    this.toString = function() {
      return this.name + ' ' + this.surname;
    }
  }
  DummyUser.prototype.toString2 = function() {
    return this.name + ' ' + this.surname;
  }
  var VipUser = function(name, age, memberId) {

  };
}());
```

Comment: Perhaps you should try making the title more descriptive. Everyone who asks a question wants some kind of solution.

Comment: Why would you expect errors? What is the actual problem you're having?

Comment: Please do not deface your own question.

Answer (score 2):

You need to move your `console.log()` like so:

```
(function() {
var User = function(name, age){
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
};
User.prototype.welcome = function(){
    console.log('Welcome ' + this.name);
};
User.prototype.getAge = function(){
    return this.age;
};

function DummyUser(name, surname) {
    this.name = name;
    this.surname = surname;
    this.toString = function() {
        return this.name + ' ' + this.surname;
    }
}
DummyUser.prototype.toString2 = function() {
    return this.name + ' ' + this.surname;
}
var VipUser = function(name, age, memberId){

};
console.log(VipUser);
console.log(DummyUser);
}());
```

See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/53socbaa/)

If you assign an anonymous function to a variable, then you cannot access it until *after* the assignment has been performed. In other words it is undefined before the assignment was made even if the anonymous function has already been 'compiled'.

From the fiddle:

```
console.log(x);
console.log(hello);

var x = function(t){
        if(t){
      return true;
    }
    return false;
}

function hello(r){
        if(r){
      return true;
    }
    return false;
}

console.log(x);
console.log(hello);
```

The output of the example code's first two logs is:

> `undefined`
>
> `hello(r){
>           if(r){
>         return true;
>       }
>       return false;
>   }`

then the second two logs output:

> `(t){
>           if(t){
>         return true;
>       }
>       return false;
>   }
>   hello(r){
>           if(r){
>         return true;
>       }
>       return false;
>   }`

Comment: Both of those symbols *are* defined.

Comment: Well `DummyUser` is hoisted, so that `console.log()` should print the function.

Comment: For further reference, see [var hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting).

Comment: @triku that sounds like a different question altogether, please create a new question. If this answered your question please upvote and accept it.